# system exception using try-catch

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a problem with making an exception. I am making a hangman game where the user needs to input a letter (box with guess) but I only want that they can give in letters from A-Z and no numbers.

In the code that I wrote, I give the box with guess the name `choosed_lettre` and convert it to "letter".

**Question**:
- How can I make the exception that it only takes letters and no numbers?

**Code**:

```
 private void Choosed_lettre_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            char letter = ' ';
            bool validation = false;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && choosed_lettre.Text != "")
            {
                do
                {
                    try //trycatch
                    {
                        string input = Convert.ToString(choosed_lettre.Text);
                        input = input.ToLower();
                        letter = Convert.ToChar(input[0]);
                        validation = true;
                    }
                    catch (SystemException)
                    {
                        choosed_lettre.Text = "";
                        return;
                    }
                } while (validation == false && !((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') && (letter >= 0 && letter <= 9)));
            }
```

**wpfscreen**:

[image: wpfscreen]

Comment: You to throw an exception if the user input letters, u can use [e.KeyCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode?view=netcore-3.1) to ignore inputs

Answer (score 1):

Sidenote: use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(choosed_lettre.Text)` instead of comparing to empty string.

`string input = Convert.ToString(choosed_lettre.Text);` is unnecessary, as `Text` porerty is already a string. Use 
`string input = choosed_lettre.Text;`

Also, *avoid exceptions that can be handled by programmer*. So, check if `input` is of length one and is a letter. Even better, you can use great method `TryParse`! Doing this will greatly simplify the code:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
    if(! char.TryParse(choosed_lettre.Text, out char letter))
        choosed_lettre.Text = "";
    if(! char.IsLetter(letter))
        choosed_lettre.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: "avoid exceptions that can be handled by programmer" Yes!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO!

Better if you use a `TextInput` handler instead:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.TextInput += MainWindow_TextInput;
}

private void MainWindow_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var isLetter = Char.IsLetter(e.Text, 0);
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?